# Stanford Return all matched expressions

Tags: stanford-nlp

Is there a way to return all the matched expressions?

Consider the following sentence

```
John Snow killed Ramsay Bolton
```

where
`John-NNP`, `Snow-NNP`, `killed- VBD`, `Ramsay-NNP`, `Bolton-NNP`

And I am using the following tag combination as rules

```
NNP-NNP
NNP-VBD
VBD-NNP
```

and expected matched words from the above rules are:

```
John Snow, Snow killed, killed Ramsay, Ramsay Bolton
```

But using the below code, I am getting only this as matched expression:

```
[John Snow, killed Ramsay]
```

Is there a way in `stanford` to get all the expected matching words from the sentence? This is the code and rule file I am using right now:

```
import com.factweavers.multiterm.SetNLPAnnotators;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.Env;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.NodePattern;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.TokenSequencePattern;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class StanfordTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String rulesFile="en.rules";
            Env env = TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv();
            env.setDefaultStringMatchFlags(NodePattern.NORMALIZE);
            env.setDefaultStringPatternFlags(Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            env.bind("collapseExtractionRules", false);

            CoreMapExpressionExtractor extractor= CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(env, rulesFile);


            String content="John Snow killed Ramsay Bolton";
            Annotation document = new Annotation(content);
            SetNLPAnnotators snlpa = new SetNLPAnnotators();
            StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = snlpa.setAnnotators("tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");
            pipeline.annotate(document);
            List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

            sentences.parallelStream().forEach(sentence -> {
                System.out.println(extractor.extractExpressions(sentence));
            });
        }
    }
```

en.rules

```
{
   ruleType:"tokens",
   pattern:([{tag:/VBD/}][ {tag:/NNP/}]),
   result:"result1"
}

{
   ruleType:"tokens",
   pattern:([{tag:/NNP/}][ {tag:/VBD/}]),
   result:"result2"
}

{
   ruleType:"tokens",
   pattern:([{tag:/NNP/}][ {tag:/NNP/}]),
   result:"result3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create different extractors for different things you want.

The issue here is that when you have two part-of-speech tag rule sequences that overlap like this, the first one that gets matched absorbs the tokens preventing the second pattern from matching.

So if (NNP, NNP) is the first rule, "John Snow" gets matched.  But then the Snow is not available to be matched with "Snow killed".

If you have a  set of patterns that overlap like this, you should disentangle them and put them in separate extractors.

So you can have a (noun, verb) extractor, and a separate (noun, noun) extractor for instance.

Comment: so if there are 10 rules, do i need to create 10 extractor objects? Is there any simple setting in Env class similar to collapseExtractionRules?